# SQL don't display ORDER BY column

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm quite new to SQL programming, so i apologize in Advance for all the irrelevant Information and stupid Questions :)

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I select data from multiple tables in the database according to different criterias. I join these datas toigether with UNION. Because UNION has its own order, I also created a column in each SELECT statement called filtering, and then at the end of the UNION I ORDERed the data BY this column> filtering. 
Then I insert my results into a table I have previously created. Until now everything functions perfectly. 
Then I close the statement, and start a new one with basically almost the same information. (Only the weekday changes from 21 to 22). I also insert these records into the new table, and there I have my "error".

Becuase of the ORDER BY column (filtering) these records are inserted into row 4, 5 and 6, instead of 1, 2 and 3.

Is there a waz to correct this, for example not to display the filtering column, or JOIN by the filtering column?

As I said I'm quite new to SQL (started learning it about about 2 Weeks ago) any help is highly appreciated!

My code and the results

```
DELETE FROM [Test].[dbo].[Übersicht_Woche_RAP]
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Übersicht_Woche_RAP] (W21, id)
SELECT SUM(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Rüsten_Ist)) AS Rüsten, 1 AS filtering
FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 21)
UNION
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Arb__Plan), 0) + ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Masch__Ist), 0) + ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), IstArb), 0)) AS B, 2 AS filtering
FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 21)
UNION
SELECT SUM(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Ausschuß)) AS C, 4 AS filtering
FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 21)
ORDER BY filtering;

INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Übersicht_Woche_RAP] (W22, id)
SELECT SUM(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Rüsten_Ist)) AS Rüsten, 1 AS filtering
FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 22)
UNION
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Arb__Plan), 0) + ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Masch__Ist), 0) + ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), IstArb), 0)) AS B, 2 AS filtering
FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 22)
UNION
SELECT SUM(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Ausschuß)) AS C, 4 AS filtering
FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 22)
ORDER BY filtering
```

[image]

Comment: *and then at the end of the UNION I ORDERed the data BY this column> filtering* The table is a unordered heap. So your `ORDER BY filtering` makes no sense and must be removed. *Becuase of the ORDER BY column (filtering) these records are inserted into row 4, 5 and 6, instead of 1, 2 and 3.* INSERT INTO cannot insert data in existing row (update this row), it always adds rows into table. You must use UPDATE - but you have lost your 'filtering' value from 1st query, so the task is unsolvable by such way.

Comment: Pick which engine you will use; SQL Server and MySQL are quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variant with direct separate SELECTs:

```
WITH
cte21 AS (SELECT SUM(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Rüsten_Ist)) AS Rüsten, 1 AS filtering
          FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
          WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 21)
          UNION
          SELECT SUM(ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Arb__Plan), 0) + ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Masch__Ist), 0) + ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), IstArb), 0)) AS B, 2 AS filtering
          FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
          WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 21)
          UNION
          SELECT SUM(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Ausschuß)) AS C, 4 AS filtering
          FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
          WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, 
          BuchDatum) = 21)
         ),
cte22 AS (SELECT SUM(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Rüsten_Ist)) AS Rüsten, 1 AS filtering
          FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
          WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 22)
          UNION
          SELECT SUM(ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Arb__Plan), 0) + ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Masch__Ist), 0) + ISNULL(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), IstArb), 0)) AS B, 2 AS filtering
          FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
          WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, BuchDatum) = 22)
          UNION
          SELECT SUM(try_convert(numeric(38, 5), Ausschuß)) AS C, 4 AS filtering
          FROM     [Test].[dbo].[ZLA01_Lang_DETAIL]
          WHERE  (ArbPl_Ist = 103100) AND (YEAR(BuchDatum) = 2019) AND (DATEPART(week, 
          BuchDatum) = 22)
         )
INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[Übersicht_Woche_RAP] (W21, W22, id)
SELECT cte21.Rüsten, cte22.Rüsten, cte21.filtering
FROM cte21
JOIN cte22 ON cte21.filtering = cte22.filtering
```

But you can create more compact version by create `cte AS (SELECT 21 weeknumber UNION SELECT 22)` and cross apply it to formalized version of your query (add GROUP BY and wrap values with MAX(), or use PIVOT).

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast Reply! It works perfect! Is there any way I can add Delete Statement before this Code, so it clears all the data in the table already, before inserting new values?

Comment: @Neymar0001 That is your data, it is up to you to decide what and when to do with them. You need to truncate table data before? add DELETE before...

Comment: Thanks everyone! I tried that, but forgot to put ";" at the end of the delete Statement, and I received an error message. (Yes i know, I'm a stupid beginner :)). I corrected that mistake, and now everything works perfectly.

Comment: People give me crap when I start CTEs with `;WITH ...` - this is another prime example why I do that.